# error in performing ajax post request for some of the data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I was asked to perform ajax post request to the php script for some of the data(student name and student gender which are yyyyty and F respectively) from the last row. By default, I want to show all the data when performing the ajax post. Then, I want to echo the selected data using the ajax post request. My code is found below............
When I performed the ajax post i got the error which states

```
Status Code: 200

ErrorThrown: SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 1634

jqXHR.responseText:

[{"student_id":"1","student_name":"Ashfur","student_gender":"F","student_age":"19","student_religion":"Muslim","student_course_id":"1"},{"student_id":"2","student_name":"Irfan","student_gender":"M","student_age":"17","student_religion":"Islam","student_course_id":"4"},{"student_id":"3","student_name":"Alice","student_gender":"F","student_age":"21","student_religion":"Chinese","student_course_id":"2"},{"student_id":"4","student_name":"Mohit","student_gender":"M","student_age":"20","student_religion":"Christian","student_course_id":"6"},{"student_id":"5","student_name":"Susy","student_gender":"F","student_age":"27","student_religion":"Chirstian","student_course_id":"5"},{"student_id":"6","student_name":"Ida","student_gender":"F","student_age":"23","student_religion":"Islam","student_course_id":"3"},{"student_id":"7","student_name":"Abdul","student_gender":"M","student_age":"22","student_religion":"Islam","student_course_id":"1"},{"student_id":"8","student_name":"Ernest","student_gender":"M","student_age":"25","student_religion":"Chinese","student_course_id":"4"},{"student_id":"9","student_name":"Wei Ling","student_gender":"F","student_age":"23","student_religion":"Chinese","student_course_id":"2"},{"student_id":"10","student_name":"Ashtae","student_gender":"M","student_age":"23","student_religion":"Islam","student_course_id":"4"},{"student_id":"11","student_name":"Jasmine","student_gender":"F","student_age":"23","student_religion":"Chinese","student_course_id":"2"},{"student_id":"65656","student_name":"yyyyty","student_gender":"F","student_age":"65","student_religion":"anything","student_course_id":"009090"}]{"student_name":"yyyyty","student_gender":"F"}
```

My html file

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Cesium-1.34/ThirdParty/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<div id="resulte"</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
showData();
function showData()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "student.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            lastOnly: true,
        },      
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('An error occurred... Look at the console (F12 or Ctrl+Shift+I, Console tab) for more information!');
            $('#resulte').html('<p>Status Code: '+jqXHR.status+'</p><p>ErrorThrown: ' + errorThrown + '</p><p>jqXHR.responseText:</p><div>'+jqXHR.responseText + '</div>');
            console.log('jqXHR:');
            console.log(jqXHR);
            console.log('textStatus:');
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log('errorThrown:');
            console.log(errorThrown);
        },

    });
};

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

In the php script

```
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','netwitness') or die ("Could not connect database");
$db = mysqli_select_db($conn,'abdpractice') or die ('Could not select database');

$result = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from student");
$json_array = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $json_array[] = $row;
}
    echo json_encode($json_array);
if (!isset($_POST["lastOnly"])){
} else {
    $response = [];
    $response['student_name'] = $json_array[count($json_array)-1]['student_name'];
    $response['student_gender'] = $json_array[count($json_array)-1]['student_gender'];

    echo json_encode($response);    
}
?>
```

I want to echo the whole data by default. when I performed the ajax post request I want to echo the selected data again... Please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: @Tariq after page load you want to display all data by default and when you send query to fetch last data via ajax post method it should display last record only ... is that exactly what u want..

Comment: @LawrenceCherone i think i do not understand on what u r saying

Comment: @ Chaitanya Ghule you read my mind ... yes that is what i want

Comment: it's simple.. to do so. just send an ajax request as soon as your document loads to fetch all data and write a form with button (in your case) to fetch only the last data.

Comment: i do not want the form with a button. can it be done without the form(button)

Comment: by default it is possible to show all data without form but when you want to show last data from your fetched records you need something to trigger your else condition in php code

Comment: other than form, button,  what else can done to trigger the else condition in php code

Comment: as you are checking for $_POST["lastOnly"] data it tells that you will require atleast a button which sends the value for lastOnly = someValue(in your case true) to trigger it

Comment: I see..... Can you modify my code based on your explanation(implementing 
 a button)???

Comment: what about debugging the data and extract the selected data?? is that poosible

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45831566/error-in-performing-ajax-post-request-for-some-of-the-data/45832559#45832559

Answer (score 2):

The error tell you what happens.

You have an invalid JSON:

```
[{"student_id":"1","student_name":"Ashfur","student_gender":"F","student_age":"19","student_religion":"Muslim","student_course_id":"1"},{"student_id":"2","student_name":"Irfan","student_gender":"M","student_age":"17","student_religion":"Islam","student_course_id":"4"},{"student_id":"3","student_name":"Alice","student_gender":"F","student_age":"21","student_religion":"Chinese","student_course_id":"2"},{"student_id":"4","student_name":"Mohit","student_gender":"M","student_age":"20","student_religion":"Christian","student_course_id":"6"},{"student_id":"5","student_name":"Susy","student_gender":"F","student_age":"27","student_religion":"Chirstian","student_course_id":"5"},{"student_id":"6","student_name":"Ida","student_gender":"F","student_age":"23","student_religion":"Islam","student_course_id":"3"},{"student_id":"7","student_name":"Abdul","student_gender":"M","student_age":"22","student_religion":"Islam","student_course_id":"1"},{"student_id":"8","student_name":"Ernest","student_gender":"M","student_age":"25","student_religion":"Chinese","student_course_id":"4"},{"student_id":"9","student_name":"Wei Ling","student_gender":"F","student_age":"23","student_religion":"Chinese","student_course_id":"2"},{"student_id":"10","student_name":"Ashtae","student_gender":"M","student_age":"23","student_religion":"Islam","student_course_id":"4"},{"student_id":"11","student_name":"Jasmine","student_gender":"F","student_age":"23","student_religion":"Chinese","student_course_id":"2"},{"student_id":"65656","student_name":"yyyyty","student_gender":"F","student_age":"65","student_religion":"anything","student_course_id":"009090"}]{"student_name":"yyyyty","student_gender":"F"}
```

The last part of the JSON is invalid: `{"student_name":"yyyyty","student_gender":"F"}`

You could use tools like https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ to see if your JSON is valid or not.

As Lawrence Cherone said, you could use json_encode.

```
$myFinalJSON = json_encode($myFirstJSON);
```

Comment: but i want to make 2 separate json..... which are the selected data and the whole data..............

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Yes, it is. I added your comment to my solution. My first solution was non-specific, just for tell Tariq an essential tool for knowning the JSON formatting. Thank you for your repply :)

Comment: @Tariq merge the arrays before you json_encode it then.

Comment: @lawrence cherone merge the array??? can you perhaps elaborate more about ur sentence

Comment: did i not merge the array??? i did extract all the data and push in to the array and then json encode

Answer (score 0):

If you want both the results to be returned in a single json response then you have to combine both the arrays

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $json_array[] = $row;
}
    //echo json_encode($json_array);
if (!isset($_POST["lastOnly"])){
} else {
    $response = [
     'student_name' = $json_array[count($json_array)-1]['student_name'],
     'student_gender' = $json_array[count($json_array)-1]['student_gender']
];
}
$json_array[] = $response;
echo json_encode($json_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Send AJAX request on window load so that all the records will be displayed
and when you fire a button to fetch last data you will get the last one from your records.

**NOTE** : Usually to fetch specific record we send a search key which is used to specify WHERE clause condition and based on that search key we execute our Sql/Mysql query.

Here, I have not send any search key and each time all records get fetched unccessarily (**causes performance issues**). Try avoiding this but just to clarify, in your case i just used a single button to trigger if-else condition and fetched all records every time just to demonstrate ajax request based on condition with php.

Below is the code

> HTML file

```
<form method='post'>
   <button id='last'>Fetch Last</button>
</form>
<div id="result"></div>
```

> JS File

```
$(window).load(function() {
    let val = 'all';
    showData(val);
});

$('#last').on('click', function() {
    let val = $(this).prop('id');
    showData(val);
});

function showData(data)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "student.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            lastOnly: data,
        },      
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('An error occurred... Look at the console (F12 or Ctrl+Shift+I, Console tab) for more information!');
            $('#resulte').html('<p>Status Code: '+jqXHR.status+'</p><p>ErrorThrown: ' + errorThrown + '</p><p>jqXHR.responseText:</p><div>'+jqXHR.responseText + '</div>');
            console.log('jqXHR:');
            console.log(jqXHR);
            console.log('textStatus:');
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log('errorThrown:');
            console.log(errorThrown);
        },

    });
};
```

> PHP File

```
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','netwitness') or die ("Could not connect database");
$db = mysqli_select_db($conn,'abdpractice') or die ('Could not select database');

$result = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from student");
$response = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $response[] = $row;
}
if (isset($_POST["lastOnly"]) && $_POST["lastOnly"] === 'last'){
    $size = count($json_array);
    $response['student_name'] = $json_array[$size-1]['student_name'];
    $response['student_gender'] = $json_array[$size-1]['student_gender'];
    echo json_encode($response); 
} else {
    echo json_encode($response);    
}
```

Also one thing to be **noted** that is -

Use `.done()` and `.fail()` methods to handle ajax response instead of using `success` and `error`.

Hope, you will get some help from this explanation. :) :)